# How to setup Three Machines with different IP Address?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have three machines, installed same ELK(6.2.2) version in all machine,

One is master and another two's are client node,

** Each machine is the different IP address

I have tried like this, but not working

**Server:**

```
    cluster.name: sever
    node.name: main-server
    node.data: true
    node.ingest: true
    node.master: true
    node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
    path.data: E:/ELK-6.2.2/elasticsearch/data
    path.logs: E:/ELK-6.2.2/elasticsearch/logs
    network.host: 11.xx.xx.xx
    http.port: 9200
    transport.tcp.port: 9300
    discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["11.XX.XX.XX",  "12.xx.xx.xx:9200", "13.xx.xx.xx:9200"]
    discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

**Client:1**

```
    cluster.name: client-one
    node.name: client-node-one
    node.data: true
    node.ingest: true
    node.master: false
    node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
    path.data: E:/ELK-6.2.2/elasticsearch/data
    path.logs: E:/ELK-6.2.2/elasticsearch/logs
    network.host: 12.xx.xx.xx
    http.port: 9200
    transport.tcp.port: 9300
    discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:  ["11.XX.XX.XX",  "12.xx.xx.xx:9200", "13.xx.xx.xx:9200"]
    discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

**Client: 2**

```
    cluster.name: client-two
    node.name: client-node-two
    node.data: true
    node.ingest: true
    node.master: false
    node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
    path.data: E:/ELK-6.2.2/elasticsearch/data
    path.logs: E:/ELK-6.2.2/elasticsearch/logs
    network.host: 13.xx.xx.xx
    http.port: 9200
    transport.tcp.port: 9300
    discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:  ["11.XX.XX.XX",  "12.xx.xx.xx:9200", "13.xx.xx.xx:9200"]
    discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

Please guide me how to setup these machines?

Answer (score 1):

*cluster.name* must be equal for all your hosts.

Comment: I changed to same cluster name for all, client node error: `not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [-1]), pinging again`

Comment: Change port from 9200 to 9300 here:  
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:  ["11.XX.XX.XX",  "12.xx.xx.xx:9200", "13.xx.xx.xx:9200"]  
And add one more config:  
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

Comment: if i add discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled : false, ES stoped and the error is  `unknown setting [discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings`

Comment: Try without this.

Comment: Server: `[2018-03-08T09:24:28,115][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-two-153] started
[2018-03-08T09:24:28,137][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [node-two-153] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state`  and Client Node: `[2018-03-08T09:24:58,616][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-one-105] started
[2018-03-08T09:25:01,626][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [node-one-105] failed to connect to master [{node-two-153}{Qf7MljmcSUi_-vYs8WAWYQ}{_NNEF_AsQrSEkLxfBiFUVQ}{10.144.250.69}{10.144.250.69:9300}], retrying...`

Comment: please send me a sample config with master and client node

Comment: Can you access from client nodes to master node? Like __telnet <master_ip> 9300__

Comment: discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["11.XX.XX.XX",  "12.xx.xx.xx:9200", "13.xx.xx.xx:9200"] - did you add port to master node? 
It should be: discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["11.XX.XX.XX:9300",  "12.xx.xx.xx:9300", "13.xx.xx.xx:9300"]

Comment: telnet : connecting to 12.xx.xx.xx:9300 ...could not open connection to the host

Comment: Check network settings for all nodes: routes and firewall. Any host should successfully ping each other and ports 9200, 9300 available.

Comment: Elastic nodes are virtual on same host? what network driver is used?

Comment: ES node located in different hosted IP address

Comment: Hi, @KarthikSaravanan Still you are looking for the solution?. If yes, do let me know if you need help on this.

Comment: Hi, @KarthikSaravanan Still you are looking for the solution?. If yes, do let me know if you need help on this.

Comment: Hi, @Sathishkumar Rakkiasamy, Thanks for your reply. I did POC to importing 100m data and check performance.